# scrapy spider not found

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to reproduce the code of this talk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eD8XVXLlUTE

When I try to run the spider:

```
scrapy crawl talkspider_basic
```

I got this error:

```
raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: talkspider_basic'
```

The code of the spider is:

```
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import  SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from pytexas.items import  PytexasItem

class TalkspiderBasicSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "talkspider_basic"
    allowed_domains = ["www.pytexas.org"]
    start_urls = ['http://wwww.pytexas.org/2013/schedule']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        dls = hcs.select('///dl')
        for dl in dls:
            times = dl.select('dt/text()').extract()
            titles = dl.select('dd/a/text()').extract()
            for time, title in zip(times,titles):
                title = title.strip()
                yield PytexasItem(title=title,time= time)
```

The code of the Items is:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PytexasItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    time = Field()
    speaker = Field()
    description = Field()
```

The name of the project and of the spider's file are

> pytexas

and

> talk_spider_basic.py

respectively, so I don't think that there is any conflict because of the names.

Edit:

It has the default structure:

```
pytexas/     
  scrapy.cfg    
  pytexas/    
    items.py   
    pipelines.py   
    settings.py   
    spiders/   
      __init__.py   
      talk_spider_basic.py
```

Comment: Could you post your project structure? Thanks.

Comment: `BaseSpider` is deprecated, just use `Spider`...how old is this tutorial?

Comment: @NickT it's from 2013

Comment: The problem is Scrapy can't find the spider. Your `scrapy.cfg` needs to specify where the settings file is correctly, then in your `settings.py` file you should have `SPIDER_MODULES = ['pytexas.spiders']` or similar. If that looks OK, what version of Scrapy and `zope.interface` do you have installed?

Comment: @NickT Is this a special case? I don't remerber I had to modify settings.py for other projects. The version of scrapy is 1.0.3 I don't know what's zope.interface

Comment: Scrapy is telling you that it can't find the spider. There are a bunch of reasons why that could happen and it's hard to diagnose without more specifics. You could try creating a new project, then creating a new spider, and see if that can "run" (doing nothing). Add stuff back in and see what breaks it.

Comment: What does `scrapy list` say?

Comment: Did you create the project with `scrapy startproject <project_name>` ?

Answer (score 2):

According Github Issues [#2254](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2254). Because some module is deprecated.Like **scrapy.contrib**.

So you should make some change.

From:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import  SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
```

To:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import XPathItemLoader
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution, which works in some situation, is downgrade your scrapy (if it is >=1.3). To do this you can run the following command:

`pip install scrapy==1.2`

Answer (score 1):

I know that this post may be old. But I have found another problem, which may produce error "spider not found". I have my spiders organized in folders, e.g `<crawler-project>/spiders/full`, `<crawler-project>/spiders/clean` . So I created new directory - `<crawler-project>/spiders/aaa` - in which I placed new spider. This new spider was not found by scrapy, until I created `__init__.py` file. **So if you want to organize spiders in folders, you should create valid python module folders**.