# Scrapy follow all the links and get status

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to follow all the links of the website and get the status of every links like 404,200. I tried this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'linkscrawl'
  item = []
  allowed_domains = ['mysite.com']
  start_urls = ['//mysite.com/']

  rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_obj", follow=True),
  )

  def parse_obj(self,response):
    item = response.url
    print(item)
```

I can see the links without status code on the console like:

```
mysite.com/navbar.html
mysite.com/home
mysite.com/aboutus.html
mysite.com/services1.html
mysite.com/services3.html
mysite.com/services5.html
```

but how to save in text file with status of all links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this as below. Hope this will help for anyone who needs.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class LinkscrawlItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    attr = scrapy.Field()

class someSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'linkscrawl'
  item = []

  allowed_domains = ['mysite.com']
  start_urls = ['//www.mysite.com/']

  rules = (Rule (LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_obj", follow=True),
  )

  def parse_obj(self,response):
    item = LinkscrawlItem()
    item["link"] = str(response.url)+":"+str(response.status)
    filename = 'links.txt'
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
      f.write('\n'+str(response.url)+":"+str(response.status)+'\n')
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: when i copy your code, i get:"No module named 'scrapy.contrib'

Comment: Which version are you using? This link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627000/scrapy-spider-not-found/46339584#41497657