# scrapy rule to follow all pages on website

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a simple spider which I want to follow all links within a domain (in this example amazon.com)
this is my code so far

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='',
            deny_extensions=['7z', '7zip', 'apk', 'bz2', 'cdr,' 'dmg', 'ico,' 'iso,' 'tar', 'tar.gz','pdf','docx'],
            ), callback='parse_item', follow=True,
            ),
    )
    custom_settings = {'LOG_ENABLED':True}
    def start_requests(self):
        #print(self.website)
        url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=water+balloons'
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_item,)

    def parse_item(self,response):
        #open_in_browser(response)
        print(response.url)
```

I checked this question but the answer didn't work [scrapy follow all the links and get status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200752/scrapy-follow-all-the-links-and-get-status), I also tried replacing `allow=''` with `restrict_xpaths='\\a'` but it didn't solve, any help is appreciated.

Note: It is important that spider stays within "amazon.com" domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the rules correctly but the problem with your code is that you are not calling the proper method inside your `start_requests` method.

In order for the rules to trigger you need to send the first request to the built-in `parse` method

Something like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    #print(self.website)
    url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=water+balloons'
    yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse)
```