# How to make scrapy spider get start URL and allowed domains from csv list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using a scrapy spider for URL crawling for my research project. My spider is based on the code from bhattraideb ([Scrapy follow all the links and get status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200752/scrapy-follow-all-the-links-and-get-status/50201374)) and slightly edited to fit my needs better.

At the moment I’m restarting the spider every time when changing the allowed domain and start URL since I need the output for each allowed domain in a separate file. Since my list of URLs is growing this is getting very tedious to do...

I tried to iterate over a .csv importing both columns with the allowed_domains and start_urls as list using "i" and "while", however it always clashes with the classes.
I'd appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see : [How to loop through multiple URLs to scrape from a CSV file in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914391/how-to-loop-through-multiple-urls-to-scrape-from-a-csv-file-in-scrapy#51914818)

For info : when not using a CSV, you can also do something like this, reading **start_urls** from a list:

```
# https://www.food.com/recipe/all/healthy?pn=1
list_url = 'https://www.food.com/recipe/all/healthy?pn='
start_urls = [list_url + str(page)]
```

Increment the page variable for the next page, until next page is None.

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed try the accepted answer which didnt work for me, however the second one did. Using the same method for allowed_domains works well too (the spider follows links so having some kind of blacklist is a must for me). Any idea on how to make the output file for each base url though? Like all URLs crawled from the URL e.g. https://www.food.com/recipe/all/ get written into www.food.com.txt?

Comment: Got it myself:
`name = re.search(r"\/\/.*?\/", str(response.url))
    nameclean = name.group()
    nameclean2 = nameclean.replace("/", "")
    filename = nameclean2 + ".txt"
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n'+str(response.url)+'\n')`

Comment: Ah, yes, or....if you would like to try output to an SQL database you could put in some conditional logic to write to a table (or multiple/different tables).